# Need to fill across data across columns while keeping column value constant, but changing row value

Tags: multiple-columns

This is what I am working with....
    In cell G34(merged Cell)... `=SUM('Enter Data Here'!Q6:R6)`

I would like to have the next cell over i34, to be able to calculate the same operation, but to reflect data one row down in another sheet.. in other words

in i34... `SUM('Enter Data Here'!Q7:R7)`

in k34.. `SUM('Enter Data Here'!Q8:R8)`

in m34... `SUM(Enter Data Here'!Q9:R9)`

in o34... `SUM('Enter Data here'!Q10:R9)`

Normally I wouldn't mind doing the calculations for each cell.. but in my current scenario I would have to type this calculation way too many times... 12 sheets, 36 columns, 6 rows...  (though I figured how to skip rows, but can't seem to skip columns)

I have tried putting the `$` in front of the column value, but when I fill across both column and row value remains the same